# Eclipse: Can you format code on save?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, code-standards

In Eclipse, under <kbd>Windows</kbd> -> <kbd>Preference</kbd> -> <kbd>Java</kbd> -> <kbd>Code Style</kbd>, you can define code templates for comments and code, and you can setup a code formatter.

I'm wondering if it is possible in Eclipse to have these setting take affect every time I save a source file.  Basically, instead of me highlighting everything and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, I want Eclipse to be responsible for making sure my code is formatted properly.

Is this possible and how do you set it up?

**Note On Using the Auto-Format:**  It's probably best to choose "Format Edited Lines" as merging changes becomes very difficult when you reformat a whole file that is in source control already that was not formatted properly. Already did this to a co-worker.

Comment: Great question, but I disagree with enabling "Format Edited Lines".  If the whole team has access to the same format XML descriptor via SCM then the team should expect their files to be reformatted.  In other words, the short term pain of merging is worth the benefit of consistent formatting.

Comment: @HDave agree.  The code should at any time be robust against a "Format Source" on all projects.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If everyone is using these settings, you can select "Format Edited Lines". It will save some time if your files are large. I agree with you about necessity of the code being robust against a "Format Source", but it's not the task of eclipse to make sure that this is the case, I think.

Comment: @brimborium a political decision.  Personally I believe that the closer you stay to default settings the smoother things will run.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That would mean the auto-format option being turned off... ;) I mean, I always save by `Ctrl+Shift+F` followed by `Ctrl+S`, so it would be fine by me, but there are other guys who don't care about formating. This feature makes our life so much easier...

Comment: Gah. Eclipse formats trivial behaviour-less getter/setter properties out to multiple-line functions.  Since studies have shown code comprehension & productivity are closely linked to vertical-space usage, I recommend keeping trivial properties compact;  3-4 lines including comment & both getter/setter.  Auto-format is for low-performing teams, not highly competent ones.

Comment: this has to be the worst idea ever

Answer (score 218, accepted):

1. In the Toolbar, navigate to: <kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd>
2. In Preferences, navigate to: <kbd>Java</kbd> → <kbd>Editor</kbd> → <kbd>Save Actions</kbd>
3. Check the following:

   - <kbd>Perform the selected actions on save</kbd>
   - <kbd>Format source code</kbd>

This may or may not be available in previous versions of Eclipse.  I know it works in:

```
Version: 3.3.3.r33x_r20080129-_19UEl7Ezk_gXF1kouft<br>
Build id: M20080221-1800
```

Comment: This looks very useful -- is there a way to achieve the same for PHP code?

Comment: Fine, but how do you do the same for non-Java files?

Comment: @PéterVarga if you're using PyDev, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043433/how-to-auto-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-eclipse#answer-3176057)

Comment: This looks very useful -- is there a way to achieve the same for C++ code?

Comment: "Preferences" is in the "Window" menu, that first step is missing from this answer.

Answer (score 16):

I have a snapshot of the setting.
Please follow the path:

In the <kbd>Preferences</kbd> window, choose <kbd>Java</kbd> --> <kbd>Editor</kbd> --> <kbd>Save Actions</kbd>.

Check the <kbd>Perform the selected actions on save</kbd>, and check the <kbd>Format source code box</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: "Preferences" is in the "Window" menu, that first step is missing from this answer.

Answer (score 14):

I strongly recommend checking your eclipse format xml descriptor into source control.  That way all members of the team can use it and you don't get to and fro reformatting battles.

Comment: Can this be done so that the XML file is installed by default?

Comment: Interesting idea, but it's incomplete and also doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that you do not have a <kbd>Save Actions</kbd> preference under <kbd>Java</kbd>--> <kbd>Editor</kbd>, it may be because you are using an older version of Eclipse. In that case you can install the Format on save plugin from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ejp/files/eclipse%20formatonsave%20plugin/).

Then, under <kbd>Preferences</kbd>, choose <kbd>Java</kbd> --> <kbd>Format on save</kbd>. Select the <kbd>Run Format</kbd> option under <kbd>Select a code formatting action</kbd>

Comment: "Preferences" is in the "Window" menu, that first step is missing from this answer.