# Aptana 3 - How remove trailing whitespaces on save

Tags: php, ide, editor

I'm trying Aptana3 but I don't find an essential feature :

Remove trailing whitespaces/empty lines on save.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not possible with Aptana 3.1. See

- http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-814

But since Aptana is (was?) based on Eclipse, you can also try

- [How to auto-remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043433/how-to-auto-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-eclipse)

Comment: I didn't know that Aptana had a bucktracker. Thanks !

Answer (score 28):

This is now possible.

Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Editors

Check "Remove trailing whitespace characters"

Comment: I believe this is enabled by default in Aptana which led to some rather obnoxious DVCS commits on legacy code that had trailing whitespace so I turned it off.  Thanks for helping me find it.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine with this Eclipse plugin http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/
Tested with Aptana 3.0.7