# Removing empty whitespace at the end of a line of text in Aptana 3

Tags: whitespace, aptana

In Aptana 2 there was this tidy thing or something like that that you could setup to remove empty whitespace from the ends of lines after saving.  You could set it to preserve empty lines and so on.  Can this be done in Aptana 3 because I'm not seeing that ability and if it is there I can't find it.

Comment: Use AnyEdit Eclipse plugin

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216571/aptana-3-how-remove-trailing-whitespaces-on-save

Answer (score 2):

Check out AnyEdit for Eclipse at http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/

It does what you are looking for and adds some nice conversion tools for characters and spaces.

I use it for web stuff (with Aptana), Android and App Engine. Works great with all of them.

When installing from the URL on that site, just select your Eclipse version and pick AnyEditTools.

Comment: I installed AnyEdit in Aptana, but it doesn't seem to be removing trailing whitespace, in fact I can't seem to find any configuration settings or options menus for it at all. It only says that it's already installed when I try to install it again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JIRA ticket currently filed against it: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-814.  You could watch the ticket for progress or add your voice there.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was implemented in Aptana Studio 3 in 2012, go to Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Editors
and in there enable Remove trailing whitespace characters. Then when you save a file you should see the whitespace disappear.