# How to auto-remove trailing whitespaces on save in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, editor, save, removing-whitespace, trailing

I don't find an essential feature in Matlab 2012b:

```
Remove trailing whitespaces on save.
```

Related:

[How to auto-remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1043433/376454)

[Aptana 3 - How remove trailing whitespaces on save](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7216571/376454)

Comment: AFAIK, this feature does not exist in the MATLAB editor. Using auto-indent (`Ctrl+i` on a selection) *does* strip all trailing whitespace, but that's a pain to do every time before a save. You could make an autohotkey script that sends `Ctrl+A, Ctrl+i, Ctrl+s right` each time you press `Ctrl+s` in the MATLAB editor window, but that's just a workaround (with unwanted sideffects) for a feature that IMHO should be part of the editor core.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same need, and wrote a little script to do something close. Put the following in a [MATLAB desktop shortcut](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_env/create-matlab-shortcuts-to-rerun-commands.html). Whenever you click the shortcut button, it will strip trailing whitespace from the active file in the editor. Not quite as good as automatically doing it on save - you need to remember to press the button before saving - but nearly. Tested on 11b, 12a, and 13b, but should also be fine on 12b.

Hope that helps!

```
% Temp variable for shortcut. Give it an unusual name so it's unlikely to
% conflict with anything in the workspace.
shtcutwh__ = struct;

% Check that the editor is available.
if ~matlab.desktop.editor.isEditorAvailable
    return
end

% Check that a document exists.
shtcutwh__.activeDoc = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
if isempty(shtcutwh__.activeDoc)
    return
end

% Get the current text.
shtcutwh__.txt = shtcutwh__.activeDoc.Text;

% Remove trailing whitespace from each line.
shtcutwh__.lines = deblank(regexp(shtcutwh__.txt,'[^\n]*(\n)|[^\n]*$', 'match'));

% Reconcatenate lines.
shtcutwh__.addNewline = @(x)sprintf('%s\n',x);
shtcutwh__.lines = cellfun(shtcutwh__.addNewline, shtcutwh__.lines, 'UniformOutput', false);
shtcutwh__.newtxt = horzcat(shtcutwh__.lines{:});

% Set the current text.
shtcutwh__.activeDoc.Text = shtcutwh__.newtxt;

% Delete temp variable.
clear shtcutwh__
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I created a Gist on github, to update Sam Roberts' answer:

It will remember your last cursor position/selection and select back after removing the trailing whitespace.

I also made it remove all trailing blank lines at the end of the editor.

I find it quite useful for longer files

https://gist.github.com/hmaarrfk/8462415

```
% To remove a Matlab trailing whitespace in the editor
% Original Author: Sam Roberts 
% http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770347/how-to-auto-remove-trailing-whitespaces-on-save-in-matlab
% Modified by Mark Harfouche to remember cursor location
%
%
% Temp variable for shortcut. Give it an unusual name so it's unlikely to
% conflict with anything in the workspace.
shtcutwh__ = struct;

% Check that the editor is available.
if ~matlab.desktop.editor.isEditorAvailable
    return
end

% Check that a document exists.
shtcutwh__.activeDoc = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
if isempty(shtcutwh__.activeDoc)
    return
end

% save the old cursor location
shtcutwh__.Selection = shtcutwh__.activeDoc.Selection;

% Get the current text.
shtcutwh__.txt = shtcutwh__.activeDoc.Text;

% Remove trailing whitespace from each line.
shtcutwh__.lines = deblank(regexp(shtcutwh__.txt,'[^\n]*(\n)|[^\n]*$', 'match'));

% remove the trailing blank lines
for n = length(shtcutwh__.lines):-1:1
    if length(shtcutwh__.lines{n}) == 0
        shtcutwh__.lines(n) = [];
    else
        break
    end
end

% Reconcatenate lines.
shtcutwh__.addNewline = @(x)sprintf('%s\n',x);

shtcutwh__.lines = cellfun(shtcutwh__.addNewline, shtcutwh__.lines, 'UniformOutput', false);

% If you always want to add a newline at the end of the file, comment this line out
% Remove the last newline character
shtcutwh__.lines{end}(end) = ''; 

shtcutwh__.newtxt = horzcat(shtcutwh__.lines{:});

% Set the current text.
shtcutwh__.activeDoc.Text = shtcutwh__.newtxt;

% Place the cursor back
shtcutwh__.activeDoc.Selection = shtcutwh__.Selection;

% Delete temp variable.
clear shtcutwh__
```

Comment: Great. I use it nearly everyday.