# How to prevent Eclipse Java Editor from automatically trimming terminal whitespaces?

Tags: eclipse, whitespace

Upon saving the file it is automatically truncating all terminal whitespaces. This is causing a big headache when creating code review diffs using a graphical tool, because hundreds of lines get modified compared to the version in source control repository, and my changes get lost in the sea.

In Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions I don't see any checkbox for enabling or disabling whitespace truncation. My Eclipse IDE version is 1.4.0.20110615-0550.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but every decent diff tool should have an option to ignore whitespace-only changes.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have *Remove trailing whitespace* on your save actions. Go to *Preferences* and select *Java - Editor - Save Actions*.

Also, see: [How to auto-remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043433/how-to-auto-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-eclipse) as you want to do the opposite.