# How do I auto-remove trailing whitespace in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Similar to the [question for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043433/how-to-auto-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-eclipse),

- How can I auto-remove trailing whitespace from the entire file being edited?
- How can I auto-remove trailing whitespace only from the lines I changed?

Comment: The real question is, why do you have whitespaces after the lines? That's abnormal.

Comment: @Raptor e.g. double space at the end of the line in markdown files generates line break (`<br>`)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can also enable it on save via the following preference (Editor -> General -> Other):

[image]

And for those wondering,

**"Always keep trailing spaces on caret line"**

> If this option is selected, trailing spaces will not be stripped on the line where the caret is placed on save operation (for example, when you switch to another window).

([bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGXe2.png))

Comment: And for those wondering, **"Always keep trailing spaces on caret line"** means _"If this option is selected, trailing spaces will not be stripped on the line where the caret is placed on save operation (for example, when you switch to another window)."_

Comment: As of 2023, the option is located in Preferences > Editor > General page, in the On Save section near the bottom.

Answer (score 9):

Ha, it's as simple as `Code->Reformat code...` (option-cmd-L)

Comment: If your project uses native debugging and includes cxx files, this will have unintended side effects, use with care.

Answer (score 1):

In Window  You can use **Ctrl + alt + enter** reformat code in your Android studio it is best way indent code properly manner

Answer (score 0):

A simple shortcut to do this easy is just **Ctrl + alt + L** .