# Eclipse pydev remove whitespaces for non python files

Tags: python, eclipse, whitespace, pydev

I enabled the auto remove the trailing whitespaces in a pydev environment for Eclipse (Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Save Actions) and it works for all my python files. 
However it doesn't apply it for other files types when I save them. Is there a way to include all the files in that automatic save action?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1043433/4175042)

Comment: Some editors (such as the Java editor) support this, others don't.

Comment: Yes, and following that guide, it works for .py files when I save them, but not for others.

Comment: Ok, installing AnyEdit made the magic. Thanks.