# Eclipse in Ubuntu deletes whitespace with CTRL+S

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu via VM-Player, and Eclipse to program in C.

Whenever I save the current code with "Ctrl+S" the cursor in the program is immediately moved to the left endpoint, unnecessarily deleting spacing (like a tab in a line after an `if` statement). It does not occur when there is code in that line, only on empty lines.

Can I change this behavior of Eclipse? I would prefer for "Ctrl+S" to save the current code and not affect whitespace.

Comment: Look at key bindings.
Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto-remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043433/how-to-auto-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-eclipse)

Comment: Only in reverse, but it tells you where the settings are.

Comment: it actually has nothing to do with ctrl+s, only with saving. after saving the eclipse moves the writing cruser to the left. How can I stop this?

Comment: ...by turning off the option to strip trailing whitespace on save?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all managed at last to do that from preferences:
**Preferences** --> **C/C++** --> **Editor** --> **Save Actions** --> uncheck **Remove trailling whitespace**.