# How to remove spaces after comments in Eclipse auto formatting?

Tags: java, eclipse, jml, openjml

I'm using the OpenJML plugin for my project, but Eclipse auto formatting messes with my JML code. JML is written after a `//@` symbol.

```
//@ requires password != null;
//@ ensures !isActive() && getPassword().testWord(password) ? isActive() && \result : isActive() == \old(isActive()) && !\result;
```

Eclipse auto formatting, however, adds a space in between of the `//` and the `@` symbols, rendering my JML code useless.

```
// @ requires password != null;
// @ ensures !isActive() && getPassword().testWord(password) ? isActive() && \result : isActive() == \old(isActive()) && !\result;
```

Is there a way in which I can disable adding a space between `//` and `@` symbols, or otherwise a way in which I can disable spacing after comments altogether?

I've tried changing the formatter profile, but I couldn't find the setting there.

I've also tried auto-removing trailing whitespace as explained here: [How to auto-remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043433/how-to-auto-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-eclipse) But that didn't work either. I assume because I'm specifically trying to change the comment auto formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto-remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043433/how-to-auto-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-eclipse)

Comment: @AxelH I don't think a question about auto-removing trailing whitespace is a duplicate of a question about Eclipse **inserting** a space after the single-line comment start (so `//@` becomes `// @`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the linked question has answer that point how to enable/disable the auto formatting that is messing with `//@`. And I keep looking on those configuration to see if the "template" can be updated.

Comment: @AxelH I have scanned the answers to that question several times, but I don't see it addressed (or at least not explicitly), and even then, the question is not a duplicate, so it should not be closed as one.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, in that case, see my answer, this will be more explicit ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be simple, disable the line comment formatting.

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter
```

Edit the current profile (you need to rename it if this is the default profile).

In the *Comment* tab, uncheck *Enable line comment formatting*.

## Reason

Even if this is possible to remove that space so that the formatting give you a correct

```
//@
```

This would impact every comment, not a big deal you can say. But what about a commented annotation ?

```
// @SuppressWarning("...")
```

This would be formatted into

```
//@SuppressWarning("...")
```

That will become a problem for the OpenJML, it will be a conflict. You can see more about that in the [User guide - 4.2 Syntactic conflicts with @](http://jmlspecs.sourceforge.net/OpenJMLUserGuide-onepage.html#x1-70004.2)

Another solution, for both annotation or JML is to disable the formatter, but this will not be usable to be honest :

```
// @formatter:off 
...
// @formatter:on
```

Everything between those tags while not be formatted (if the `formatter:on` is omitted, everything after that in the file won't be formatted