# Eclipse: How remove trailing white spaces on all lines for a non Java file?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

In Eclipse IDE (or in my case `STS`) for a java file about: *remove trailing white spaces on all lines* I am able to do the following:

[image]

Practically how is described in:

- [How to auto-remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618521/3665178)

Thus from the figure shown above you can see:

- `Remove trailing white spaces on all lines`

Until all work fine, but for development, we have files with other extensions. Thus I need have the same feature for a non java file, for example for: `.xml`, `.js`, `.gradle`, `.html`, `.css`, `.properties`, `.sql` files, etc.

I could not find a specific section to accomplish this.

How I can accomplish this required configuration?

Comment: It is up to the individual editors to implement this. If it isn't listed in the preferences for a particular editor it isn't supported by the editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unforunately there is no generic solution to automatically remove trailing whitespace in Eclipse. See:

- Open Eclipse [Bug 180349 - Remove trailing spaces as an option while saving files](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=180349).
- Closed duplicate [Bug 311173 - Remove trailing whitespace on touched lines](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=311173)

However, there is a plugin named [AnyEdit Tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) which removes trailing whitespace on any file, with no configuration necessary beyond installing the plugin and restarting Eclipse.

There are two ways you can install it:

1. Using **Help -> Install new Software...**

   - Enter http://andrei.gmxhome.de/eclipse/ as the URL in the **Work with** field.
   - Select **AnyEditTools** option for all recent releases of Eclipse (3.8+), and complete the wizard.

     [image: installAnyEditTools]
2. Using **Help > Eclipse Marketplace...**

   - Enter *AnyEdit* in the **Find** field to locate the **AnyEdit Tools** plugin.
   - Click the **Install** button.

     [image: installAnyEditTools2]

Once Eclipse is restarted the plugin should automatically remove trailing spaces on any file when you save it, regardless of type or extension. For example:

- Create a new file with some arbitrary extension unknown to Eclipse (e.g. *test.abcxyz*).
- Enter some data in the file, with some lines having trailing spaces.
- Save it. The trailing spaces are gone.

This plugin works for me on Photon.

**AnyEdit** can do a lot of other things as well. This is the summary for the installed plugin:

> Adds useful context menu actions to text files and editors - Open
>   file, type under cursor, Convert tabs to spaces, case, html, base64,
>   unicode, Compare/Replace with clipboard or external files etc. AnyEdit
>   can remove trailing whitespace and/or convert tabs-spaces on save and
>   contributes Import/Export working sets wizards.

See [the web site for the plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, consider add the Marketplace option too. It with the purpose to share the two options to install it.

Comment: @ManuelJordan OK - I verified that the plugin also works when installed through the MarketPlace option and updated the answer, and also added the plugin's summary of its features.