# Format XML on save in eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse: auto format XML files on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677110/eclipse-auto-format-xml-files-on-save)

I know this can be done with Java files, and newer ADT versions update XML. But for a non Android developer is it possible to make a set of rules for XML (e.g. remove whitespace) which can be applied on save?

Comment: The question this duplicates refers to developers installing android developer tools as an addition. This question is intended for non-android developers and those without ADT.