# Eclipse Wild Web Developer Generic Editor: How to share the language server XML formatting settings within a team?

Tags: java, eclipse, language-server-protocol, xml-formatting, wildwebdeveloper

So far we have used the XML Editor from the Web Tools Platform (WTP).

- It [does not support save-actions for automatic formatting on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677110/eclipse-auto-format-xml-files-on-save).
- It does not support project-specific formatting settings (only workspace settings)

I am now learning that the Wild Web Developer project provides an alternative editor for XML files, called "Generic Editor".

- It can be set as default in Preferences - File Associations
- It ignores the workspace XML Editor settings, and instead uses a [language server (LemMinX)](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx)
- I see some language server settings in the workspace Preferences (see screenshot)

Now I have the same question as with the WTP Editor:

Are there any project specific configuration files that we can put under version control to ensure that every team member automatically uses the same formatting settings for each project?

[image]